# Call an AsyncTask subclass of activity from another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know this kind of questions are maybe too old, but I got stock with this silly thing.
I have an AsyncTask class which is a subclass of an activity class, and right now I want to call it from another class: following codes shows what I mean:

```
  public class STA extends Activity {

public class ListSpdFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    private static final String TAG = "ListSpdFiles: ";

    /**
     * Status code returned by the SPD on operation success.
     */
    private static final int SUCCESS = 4;

    private String initiator;
    private String path;

    private SecureApp pcas;
    private boolean isConnected = false;  // connected to PCAS service?

    private PcasConnection pcasConnection = new PcasConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onPcasServiceConnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "pcasServiceConnected");
            latch.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPcasServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "pcasServiceDisconnected");
        }
    };
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


    public ListSpdFiles(String initiator, String path) {
        this.initiator = initiator;
        this.path = path;

    }

    private void init() {
        Log.d(TAG, "starting task");
        pcas = new AndroidNode(getApplicationContext(), pcasConnection);
        isConnected = pcas.connect();
    }

    private void term() {
        Log.d(TAG, "terminating task");
        if (pcas != null) {
            pcas.disconnect();
            pcas = null;
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // check if connected to PCAS Service
        if (!isConnected) {
            Log.v(TAG, "not connected, terminating task");
            return null;
        }

        // wait until connection with SPD is up
        try {
            if (!latch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "unable to connected within allotted time, terminating task");
                return null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "interrupted while waiting for connection in lsdir task");
            return null;
        }

        // perform operation (this is where the actual operation is called)
        try {
            return lsdir();
        } catch (DeadServiceException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "service boom", e);
            return null;
        } catch (DeadDeviceException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "device boom", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] listOfFiles) {
        super.onPostExecute(listOfFiles);
        if (listOfFiles == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "task concluded with null list of files");
            // tv.setText("task concluded with a null list of files");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "task concluded with the following list of files: "
                    + Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
            //tv.setText("List of files received is:\n" + Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
        }
        term();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String[] listOfFiles) {
        super.onCancelled(listOfFiles);
        Log.i(TAG, "lsdir was canceled");
        term();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an array of strings containing the files available at the given path, or
     * {@code null} on failure.
     */
    private String[] lsdir() throws DeadDeviceException, DeadServiceException {
        Result<List<String>> result = pcas.lsdir(initiator, path);  // the lsdir call to the
        final Global globalVariable = (Global) getApplicationContext();

        if (globalVariable.getPasswordButt() == false) {

            // Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)


            // Get name and email from global/application context
            final boolean isusername = globalVariable.getIsUsername();

            if (isusername == true) {

                String username = "/" + getLastAccessedBrowserPage() + ".username" + ".txt";
                //String password = "/" + CurrentURL + "password" + ".txt";
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                pcas.readFile(initiator, username, baos);
                Log.i(TAG, "OutputStreampassword: "
                        + new String(baos.toByteArray()));
                String name = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    globalVariable.setUsername(name);
                   // getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(name, 1);
                    // updateCandidates();
                }

                globalVariable.setIsUsername(false);
            } else if (isusername == false)
                Log.i(TAG, "Wrong Input Type For Username.");
            //  globalVariable.setUsernameButt(false);


        } else if (globalVariable.getPasswordButt() == true) {

            // Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
            // final Global globalVariable = (Global) getApplicationContext();

            // Get name and email from global/application context
            final boolean ispassword = globalVariable.getIsPassword();

            if (ispassword == true) {
                // String username = "/" + CurrentURL + "username" + ".txt";
                String password = "/" + getLastAccessedBrowserPage() + ".password" + ".txt";
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                pcas.readFile(initiator, password, baos);
                Log.i(TAG, "OutputStreampassword: "
                        + new String(baos.toByteArray()));
                String name = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    globalVariable.setPassword(name);
                    //getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(name, 1);
                    // updateCandidates();
                }

                globalVariable.setIsPassword(false);
            } else if (ispassword == false)
                Log.i(TAG, "Wrong Input Type For Password.");

            globalVariable.setPasswordButt(false);
            // boolpassword=false;
        }

        //}
        if (result.getState() != SUCCESS) {
            Log.v(TAG, "operation failed");
            return null;
        }
        if (result.getValue() == null) {
            Log.v(TAG, "operation succeeded but operation returned null list");
            return null;
        }

        return result.getValue().toArray(new String[0]);
    }

}

public String getLastAccessedBrowserPage() {
    String Domain = null;

    Cursor webLinksCursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
    int row_count = webLinksCursor.getCount();

    int title_column_index = webLinksCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
    int url_column_index = webLinksCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);

    if ((title_column_index > -1) && (url_column_index > -1) && (row_count > 0)) {
        webLinksCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (webLinksCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            if (webLinksCursor.getInt(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_BOOKMARK_INDEX) != 1) {
                if (!webLinksCursor.isNull(url_column_index)) {
                    Log.i("History", "Last page browsed " + webLinksCursor.getString(url_column_index));
                    try {
                        Domain = getDomainName(webLinksCursor.getString(url_column_index));
                        Log.i("Domain", "Last page browsed " + Domain);
                        return Domain;

                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            webLinksCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    webLinksCursor.close();
    return null;

}

public String getDomainName(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String domain = uri.getHost();
    return domain.startsWith("www.") ? domain.substring(4) : domain;
}}
```

Would you please tell me what should I do to fix this code?

Comment: Best bet would be to make it so `ListSpdFiles` is no longer an inner class and dependent on `STA`. Then you can use it in both activities. What is done in `onPostExecute()` of `ListSpdFiles`? Does it update UI components?

Comment: no, it does not.
      @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] listOfFiles) {
            super.onPostExecute(listOfFiles);
            if (listOfFiles == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "task concluded with null list of files");
                // tv.setText("task concluded with a null list of files");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "task concluded with the following list of files: "
                        + Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));
                //tv.setText("List of files received is:\n" + Arrays.toString(listOfFiles));}
            term();

Comment: I see you have the `tv.setText()` calls commented but what does the `term()` method do? Was that a method in your `STA` activity? Is there a similar method in the new class you want to use the `AsyncTask` in?

Comment: private void term() {
            Log.d(TAG, "terminating task");
            if (pcas != null) {
                pcas.disconnect();
                pcas = null;
                isConnected = false;
            }
        }

Comment: The only methods STA activity has is getlasturlvisited() and getdoamin().
And there is no similar method in my new class

Comment: Is `term()` a method on `ListSpdFiles` then? I'm trying to figure out how to make that task useful to both classes but am not sure how you are using the results. It's probably easiest if you share that code. Otherwise one common approach is to implement an interface in both your classes that use the `AsyncTask` and keep a reference in `ListSpdFiles` to that interface. Then when the task completes you can call something like `fileListener.onListOfFilesRetrieved()` and do whatever you want with the results in each class.

Comment: Well I have updated my previous code, you can see the entire class of STA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the code I did not see anywhere you referenced anything from the `Activity` itself besides the application context so you can move the `ListSpdFiles` class to its own java file and pass it a context into the constructor when you make a new instance of it.

Put this class in a ListSpdFiles.java file so it is no longer an inner class.

```
public class ListSpdFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
    Context applicationContext;

    public ListSpdFiles(Context context, String initiator, String path) {
        this.initiator = initiator;
        this.path = path;
        applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    // The rest of your code still goes here. Replace other calls to
    // getApplicationContext() with the new applicationContext field
}
```

You can now use this class anywhere a `Context` is available. You create a new instance by doing:

```
ListSpdFiles listSpdFilesTask = new ListSpdFiles(context, "someInitiator", "somePath");
listSpdFilesTask.execute();
```

Comment: That is also a method of `Context` so use `applicationContext.getContentResolver(...)`

Comment: Thank you vary much.
Right now I got another error, I have set some global variables by using 
 final Global globalVariable = (Global) applicationContext;
and  globalVariable.setUsername(name);
in listspdfiles class
but when I want to get that global var in other class it returns null.
I think it is because I of context 
Could you help me how to solve that?

Comment: here is one of the methods of another class:
 private void handle_username_paste() { // handle username_paste_button
        ListSpdFiles listSpdFilesTask = new ListSpdFiles(getApplicationContext(), INITIATOR, "/");
        listSpdFilesTask.execute();

        final Global globalVariable = (Global) getApplicationContext();
        final String name = globalVariable.getUsername();
        Log.i(TAG, "usernamesoftkey: "
                + name);
    }